# Java Algoirthm number of Combinations of variables (Similar to Bit String Algoirthm)

Tags: java, combinations, bitstring

I have a problem I'm trying to solve in Java and I cannot figure out the algorithm that I'm going to need to follow. This problem is similar to the Bit String problem (how many bit strings are there of length x), but with some added difficulty. I'm not even sure the algorithm for solving the normal bit string problem anyway.

So here's my actual problem:
I have 5 variables. Say Q W X Y Z. Each variable can take one of 3 values (so like bit string can take 1 or 0, but this can take say 0, 1, or 2). I need to generate all possible combinations of this "bit string".

So one combination may be 00000 another may be 10002, another could be 22222, etc. I need to print out all combinations of this "bit string"

I'm really stumped on how to solve this problem or even come up with a decent algorithm.

Thanks for the help! Much appreciated.

Comment: No it's part of a side project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this, you could just count up to your maximum value (22222 in your example) using a radix of 3. The BigInteger class supports output and instantiation with an arbitrary radix. The BigInteger class, however, does not support zerofill which is why I added this myself. Here is the resulting solution:

```
public static void main( String[] args ) {
    System.out.println( new BitStrings().generateBitStrings( new BigInteger( "2222", 3 ) ) );
}

public List<String> generateBitStrings( BigInteger maxValue ) {
    final String format = "%0" + maxValue.toString( 3 ).length() + "d";
    BigInteger current = BigInteger.ZERO;
    final List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>( maxValue.intValue() );
    do {
        result.add( String.format( format, Long.valueOf( current.toString( 3 ) ) ) );
        current = current.add( BigInteger.ONE );
    } while(current.compareTo( maxValue ) <= 0);
    return result;
}
```

Output:

```
[0000, 0001, 0002, 0010, 0011, 0012, 0020, 0021, 0022, 0100, 0101, 0102, 0110, 0111, 0112, 0120, 0121, 0122, 0200, 0201, 0202, 0210, 0211, 0212, 0220, 0221, 0222, 1000, 1001, 1002, 1010, 1011, 1012, 1020, 1021, 1022, 1100, 1101, 1102, 1110, 1111, 1112, 1120, 1121, 1122, 1200, 1201, 1202, 1210, 1211, 1212, 1220, 1221, 1222, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2100, 2101, 2102, 2110, 2111, 2112, 2120, 2121, 2122, 2200, 2201, 2202, 2210, 2211, 2212, 2220, 2221, 2222]
```

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: You can just make `generateBitStrings` static, then you wouldn't need to create a `BitStrings` instance to use the method.

Comment: @A.R.S. I know, but this is neither relevant to the answer nor do I think that static methods are good design in general.

Comment: Why do you think they are not a good design? They are one of the most fundamental components of the Java programming language.

Comment: @A.R.S. Java's main design paradigm is object-orientation and static methods do not fit into this (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4002201/why-arent-static-methods-considered-good-oo-practice and http://misko.hevery.com/2008/12/15/static-methods-are-death-to-testability/) - they are part of the language, but that does not mean that they contribute to good design.

Comment: Yes I agree with you in the sense that, more-or-less, static methods are not completely OO concepts (like one of the links stated). But, there is no reason to not use the utilities a language offers. In fact, it is considered VERY bad practice in Java to instantiate a class simply to call a method that is not at all related with that instance. Don't you think that seems a bit pointless when a static method could simply be used?

Comment: @A.R.S. As I already said, this is not relevant to the answer. Actually, the method `generateBitStrings` is the answer. The main method is just to illustrate its usage with an example. And no, I don't agree that it is very bad practice to instantiate a class to just call a method. Object instantiation is very cheap in Java, especially if there is no state to initialize. The author of the question may opt to make this method static which is perfectly fine. He may also decide to rename it, change its visibility or add a Javadoc comment - my answer just demonstrates the approach.

Comment: Alright fair enough. It's really your choice I guess and no it isn't relevant to this answer as long as the OP understands the methodology behind the `generateBitStrings` method.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

public class Generator implements Iterable<String> {

    private int len;
    public Generator(int len) {
        this.len = len;
    }

    public Iterator<String> iterator() {
        return new Itr(len);
    }

    private class Itr implements Iterator<String> {
        private int[] a;
        private boolean done;

        public Itr(int len) {
            a = new int[len];
            done = false;
        }

        @Override
        public String next() {
            if (done) throw new NoSuchElementException();
            String s = getString();
            step(a.length - 1);
            return s;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() { return !done; }

        @Override
        public void remove() {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }

        private void step(int index) {
            if (a[index] == 2) {
                if (index == 0) {
                    done = true;
                    return;
                }
                a[index] = 0;
                step(index - 1);
            } else
                a[index]++;
        }

        private String getString() {
            StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i : a)
                s.append(i);
            return s.toString();
        }
    }

}
```

Then you could do something like this:

```
Generator g = new Generator(2 /* length of resulting strings */);
for (String s : g)
    System.out.println(s);
```

Output:

> 00
>   10
>   20
>   01
>   11
>   21
>   02
>   12
>   22

Basically, all we're doing here is counting upwards in base-3 until we reach `222...222` (where the number of `2`s is specified when instantiating a `Generator`). Hope this helps!

Comment: Iterators are not supposed to change the internal state of the collection iterated over when the method `next()` is called, which your iterator does. After the first iteration, a second one would not work. Further, the remove method should throw an `UnsupportedOperationException` instead of doing just nothing which would make the user think that element removal is supported and was successful.

Comment: See my edit above, now a `Generator` can be used more than once. In this case, we're not really iterating over a collection. And we don't need to worry about changing `a` since the user has no access to it anyway.

Comment: The method `hasNext()` will now return different values for two successive calls without an intermediate call to the `next()` method which does not make sense considering the `Iterator` interface. Further, instantiating two iterators and calling their methods alternating will not work as expected.

Comment: Quite honestly, the OP can sort out such technicalities if he/she requires a higher degree of flexibility. What's important is the methodology behind this.

Comment: You should not use the `Iterable` interface then - it comes with a well-defined behavior. As long as there is only the use-case you have shown, there won't be any problems and so nobody would ever change the implementation. At some point in future, it may be used in another way and nobody has an idea that the implementation does not comply with the documentation of the interface declared. Further, the implementation cannot be tested against the definitions of the interface as thorough tests would fail then. In short, I'm sorry, but I don't think your solution is good as it is now.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16474/discussion-between-a-r-s-and-michael-schmeisser)

Answer (score 2):

You need to consider the *math* behind it. It makes things a lot easier when you've understood how to *enumerate* these strings. This will yield an obvious way not only of *generating* the strings, but also allow you to "random access" them, i.e. you can also write a `get(int num)` method that will produce the `num`th element.

The math is pretty simple, it only involves modulo operations (`%`) and divisions, and it really pays off when you figure this out *yourself*.

As a simple first preparation, assume that you have `n` decimal digits.

- Given a number `x`, how do you get the `n`th digit?
- Given `n` digits, how do you get the number `x`?

After you have figured this out, try to abstract from having `10` digits. Say, practise counting in binary. Then in ternary, which will be your solution for 3 digits.

Answer (score 1):

This should be a relatively easy problem to solve.

Essentially, you're merely computing the set of [*strings*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_%28computer_science%29#Formal_theory) *Σ^5* where *Σ = { 0, 1, 2 }*.

```
static Iterable<String> strings(final int radix, final int digits) {
  return new Iterable<String>() {

    public Iterator<String> iterator() {
      return new Iterator<String>() {

        private final int hi = (int) Math.pow(radix, digits);
        private int cursor;

        public boolean hasNext() {
          return cursor < hi;
        }

        public String next() {
          int v = cursor++;
          int n = digits;
          final char[] buf = new char[n];
          while (n > 0) {
            buf[--n] = (char) (v % radix + '0');
            v /= radix;
          }
          return new String(buf);
        }

        public void remove() {
          throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }
      };
    }
  };
}
```

... which can be used as follows:

```
for (final String val : strings(3, 5)) {
  System.out.println(val);
}
```

Basically, we generate the numbers in the interval *[0, 3^5)*, where *3* is our radix and *5* our desired string length, and then convert the numbers into [ternary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_numeral_system) form. *0* becomes *00000*, *3^5* becomes *100000*.