# Count in base 2, 3, 4 etc in Java and output all permutations

Tags: java, binary, permutation, combinations, counting

I want to write a function in Java that takes as input an integer and outputs every possible permutation of numbers up to that integer. For example:

f(1)

0

f(2) should output:

00
01
10
11

f(3) should output:

000
001
002
010
011
012
020
021
022
100
....
220
221
222

That is it should output all 27 permutations of the digits of the numbers 0, 1, 2.

f(4) should output
0000 0001 0002 0003 0010 ... 3330 3331 3332 3333

f(5) should output
00000 00001 ... 44443 44444

I have been trying to solve this problem but cannot seem to work out how to do it and keep getting confused by how many loops I need. Does anyone know how to solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like homework.  If so, you should tag it as such.  Also, what have you tried?

Comment: No this is not homework. It is part of a much bigger piece of code that I am writing for graph exploration.

Comment: I'm trying to understand the question. The last value that f(1) prints is 0, the last value that f(2) prints is 11. The last value that f(3) prints is 222. Does this progress to 3333, 44444, 555555, 6666666...?

Comment: Yes Bob that is correct.

Comment: You need three things: 1) one loop that counts from 0 to your last value, 2) a function to calculate your last value, 3) and a function to format each individual value. Given that, is there a particular piece that you're having trouble with?

Comment: Yeah how do I calculate the "last value"?

Comment: That is the essence of software development! Look at your values, establish a pattern, come up with a function that works in the first few cases then see if it works for all cases. I'll take a crack at it, but it'll take a few minutes. EDIT: ... or we could have a look at oldrimb's solution below...

Comment: Is max argument for that method 10? If not What would be last result of f(11)? `10_10_10_10_10_10_10_10_10_10_10` (I used "_" for better readability) or maybe something like `aaaaaaaaaa` like in Hexadecimal?

Comment: No there is no maximum argument. I have just printed out the numbers without spaces for the output but in my actual code I will use the number output and the printed output is not that important.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Quickest way to convert a base 10 number to any base in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/923771/quickest-way-to-convert-a-base-10-number-to-any-base-in-net)

Comment: @tree-hacker you only want integers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just count and convert. I wrote something should help in an earlier answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12334800/591495).

> This should be a relatively easy problem to solve.
>
> Essentially, you're merely computing the set of [*strings*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_(computer_science)#Formal_theory) *Σ^5* where *Σ = { 0, 1, 2 }*.
>
> ```
> static Iterable<String> strings(final int radix, final int digits) {
>   return new Iterable<String>() {
>
>     public Iterator<String> iterator() {
>       return new Iterator<String>() {
>
>         private final String pad;
>         {
>           final StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder(digits);
>           for (int n = digits; n >= 0; --n) {
>             buf.append('0');
>           }
>           pad = buf.toString();
>         }
>
>         private final int hi = (int) Math.pow(radix, digits);
>         private int cursor;
>
>         public boolean hasNext() {
>           return cursor < hi;
>         }
>
>         public String next() {
>           final String rsl = Integer.toString(cursor++, radix);
>           return pad.substring(0, digits - rsl.length()) + rsl;
>         }
>
>         public void remove() {
>           throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
>         }
>       };
>     }
>   };
> }
> ```
>
> ... which can be used as follows:
>
> ```
> for (final String val : strings(3, 5)) {
>   System.out.println(val);
> }
> ```
>
> Basically, we generate the numbers in the interval *[0, 3^5)*, where *3* is our radix and *5* our desired string length, and then convert the numbers into [ternary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_numeral_system) form. *0* becomes *00000*, *3^5* becomes *100000*. You must also take care to not use too large a radix, otherwise the resulting `String` will contain bad characters.

---

The solution here is to merely call `strings(n, n)`. Note that, depending on how large your radix or desired digit lengths are, you may wish to instead use `long` or even `BigInteger`.

Also, since it relies on [`Integer.toString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toString(int,%20int)), make sure you remember the following caveat...

> If the radix is smaller than `Character.MIN_RADIX` or larger than `Character.MAX_RADIX`, then the radix `10` is used instead.

You can see the value for [`Character.MIN_RADIX`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.lang.Character.MIN_RADIX) is `2` and [`MAX_RADIX`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.lang.Character.MAX_RADIX) is `36`. If you use a radix outside of this range, it will default to `10`... you will need to write your own conversion with a custom extended character set for digits. The general form of such an `itoa` function is as follows:

```
    private static final char[] ALPHABET = { '0', '1', '2', '3', ... };

    public static String itoa(int value, final int radix, int width) {
      final char[] buf = new char[width];
      while (width > 0) {
        buf[--width] = ALPHABET[value % radix];
        value /= radix;
      }
      return new String(buf);
    }
```

---

Below is a working example for your usage (see result on [ideone](http://ideone.com/Lg9yw)).

```
static Iterable<String> f(final int n) {
  return strings(n, n);
}

public static void main(final String[] argv) {
  for (int n = 1; n <= 5; ++n) {
    for (final String string : f(n)) {
      System.out.printf("%s ", string);
    }
    System.out.println();
  }
}
```

... which produces:

> 0
>
> 00 01 10 11
>
> 000 001 002 010 011 012 020 021 022 100 101 102 110 111 ...
>
> 0000 0001 0002 0003 0010 0011 0012 0013 0020 0021 0022 0023 0030 ...
>
> 00000 00001 00002 00003 00004 00010 00011 00012 00013 00014 00020 00021 00022 ...