# Loading screen - JFrame setvisible from other class

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, jframe

I want a temporary loading screen in the transition from one frame to another.
In the mainframe I create the loading screen which creates the other screen (employmentframe). It only creates it, it does not show it yet.

In the employment frame I have put some `loadingframe.setloadingbar()` methods which call the `setloadingbar` method in loadingframe. This works perfect until it reaches 100. At `getvalue() == 100` it should set the `employmentframe` visible, but instead it gives me a `nullpointerexception`. Which is weird because the employment-screen IS created.

The code is below -

**Employmentframe:**

```
   public EmploymentFrame(int eid, JFrame thisframe) {         
        initComponents();
        //loadCaseFileList();
        e_id = eid;
        loadCourseList();
        EmploymentFrame.thisframe = thisframe;
        LoadingFrame.setLoadingBar(1);
    }
    public static void setEmploymentFrameVisible()
    {
       thisframe.setVisible(true);
    }
```

**The loadingframe:**

```
private static JFrame Employmentframe;
private static int oldvalue;
private int e_id;
public LoadingFrame(int type, int eid) {
    initComponents();
    this.e_id = eid;
    if(type == 1)
    {
        Employmentframe = new EmploymentFrame(eid, Employmentframe); 
    }
}

   public static void setLoadingBar(int load)
   {
       oldvalue = LoadingBar.getValue();
       System.out.println(""+oldvalue);
       int newvalue = oldvalue+load;
       System.out.println("nv"+newvalue);
       LoadingBar.setValue(newvalue);
       if(LoadingBar.getValue() == 100)
       {
           EmploymentFrame.setEmploymentFrameVisible();
       }
   }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the exception to see where is being thrown.

Comment: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at nypdapp.EmploymentFrame.setEmploymentFrameVisible(EmploymentFrame.java:36)
 at nypdapp.LoadingFrame.setLoadingBar(LoadingFrame.java:39)

Answer (score 1):

The stacktrace indicates that this line is throwing the `NPE`

```
thisframe.setVisible(true);
```

so `thisframe` is `null`.

When you create `Employmentframe` here

```
Employmentframe = new EmploymentFrame(eid, Employmentframe);
```

you are passing in `null` as an argument to the constructor as the `JFrame` has not yet been initialized. In fact, the `EmploymentFrame` does not need to be passed an instance of itself.

---

There are a number of other issues:

- Static methods are seen as a [poor design choice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4002201/why-arent-static-methods-considered-good-oo-practice) in any OO language
- Multiple `JFrames` are considered difficult to manage. Preferred alternatives are 1.) [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) on a single `JFrame` or 2.) In cases where multiple windows *are* required a single `JFrame` with a modal `JDialog` can be used. Also discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554636/the-use-of-multiple-jframes-good-bad-practice).
- Code conventions in Java indicate that variables should begin with a lowercase letter.

Comment: So what I have done right now is add an internal frame with the loading stuff in it and make it visible when pressed on the empbutton. then inside the empbutton's code it does: newframe = new EmploymentFrame(this_eid); NewFrame is a static private jframe declared at the top of the code. But then still it is null when called newframe.setvisible(true); at the loadingbar's code. How?

Comment: It's difficult to to comment without seeing the code. Consider posting an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). Again `static` methods are poor, lead to problems such as this.

Comment: I dont see another way to use a other-class method without it being a static one (excuse me for being an amateur).   
   
`code`private static int oldvalue;
    private static JFrame newframe;
    public static void setLoadingBar(int load)
    {
        oldvalue = LoadingBar.getValue();
        int newvalue = oldvalue+load;
        LoadingBar.setValue(newvalue);
        if(LoadingBar.getValue() == 100)
        {
            newframe.setVisible(true);
        }
    }
public EmploymentFrame(int eid) {         
        initComponents();
        //MainFrame.setLoadingBar(100);
    }

Comment: Here's a link to a codepaste page where I pasted the code. Im new to this site, so please excuse me.
[link]http://codepaste.net/rdb3ts

Comment: I would say to paste to the whole code to that site. Snippets are not really helpful.