# Disadvantages of using all static methods as opposed to other "service" classes?

Tags: java, static

I have a simple `Java` application that carries out all its logic in the `main method` of one class.

Currently I have just created methods in this class, declared them as `Static` and called them in the main.

Is this approach preferred over e.g. creating a `"service"` class then creating an instance of it to invoke my methods?

Comment: a disadvantage: if one instance changes something for the method, it changes for all the calls made to it, since it is static

Comment: can you please elaborate on this?

Comment: you mean explain to you what static is? This is quite basic. Just lookup java static vs instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your methods are puerly functional (no side-effects), then it's ok to use static methods. If they have side-effects (such as changing static class members), this design is dangerous as other parts of the system may suddenly break.

A more general problem is that its hard to unit-test such static methods, as they cannot easily be mocked. I this case it is preferrable to use a stingleton implementing an interface. This singleton can then be mocked by a "dummy"-implementation

see also this question on SO: [Why aren't static methods considered good OO practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4002201/why-arent-static-methods-considered-good-oo-practice)