# Typescript abstract class static method not enforced

Tags: typescript, interface, static, abstract-class, static-typing

I have this simple code in TypeScript:

```
abstract class Config {
    readonly NAME: string;
    readonly TITLE: string;

    static CoreInterface: () => any
}

class Test implements Config {
    readonly NAME: string;
    readonly TITLE: string;
}
```

Even though the *CoreInterface()* member is missing in the *Test* class, TypeScript does not complain. Why is this?

I need every derived class to provide some metadata about itself in the *CoreInterface()* static function. I know I could just extend the Config class and have each sub-class provide its own implementation of *CoreInterface()*, but I do not want sub-classes to automatically inherit any of the members of the COnfig class. That is why I use "implements" instead of "extends"

Comment: Because it's not a member. It's a static field, which thus belongs to the class, and not to the instance of the class.

Comment: So is there no way to enforce that any class derived from Config MUST implement _CoreInterface()_?

Comment: abstract class Config implements CoreInterface? Is that what you want?

Comment: And how will you represent _CoreInterface()_? Can you post example code of your solution here?

Comment: Implementing an interface means: any **instance** of a class that implements Config will have these instance fields and instance methods. Since CoreInterface is a static member, it's irrelevant. Static members belong to classes, not instances. And they're not called polymorphically. If you're trying to impose that every implementation must have a given static member, then AFAIK, it's not possible (and I don't understand what purpose it would serve). What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: No, I simply want to indicate that any class that derives from Config must implement the specific static function CoreInterface()

Comment: >> "it's not possible (and I don't understand what purpose it would serve). What are you trying to achieve?" I need every derived class to provide some metadata about itself in the CoreInterface() static function. I realizes I could probably just extend the super class and have each sub class provide its own implementation of CoreInterface(), but I do not want want sub-classes to automatically inherit any of the members of the super-class. That is why I use "implements" instead of "extends"

Comment: AFAIK, that's not possible. But I would probably use the reverse strategy: have a collection of metadata objects, all having a class extending Config (or some factory function allowing to create a Config subclass instance)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Based on your comment, here's how you can achieve what you're looking for:

```
interface ConfigConstructor {
    CoreInterface: () => any;
    new (): Config;
}

interface Config {
    readonly NAME: string;
    readonly TITLE: string;
}

const Test: ConfigConstructor = class Test implements Config {
    readonly NAME: string;
    readonly TITLE: string;

    static CoreInterface = function (): any { return "something"; }
}
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20ConfigConstructor%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20CoreInterface%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20any%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20new%20()%3A%20Config%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20Config%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20readonly%20NAME%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20readonly%20TITLE%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20Test%3A%20ConfigConstructor%20%3D%20class%20Test%20implements%20Config%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20readonly%20NAME%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20readonly%20TITLE%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20static%20CoreInterface%20%3D%20function%20()%3A%20any%20%7B%20return%20%22something%22%3B%20%7D%0D%0A%7D))

If you comment out one of the members (i.e.: `NAME`) you'll get this error:

> Class 'Test' incorrectly implements interface 'Config'.
>   Property 'NAME' is missing in type 'Test'.

If you comment out the static `CoreInterface` you'll get this error:

> Type 'typeof Test' is not assignable to type 'ConfigConstructor'.
>   Property 'CoreInterface' is missing in type 'typeof Test'.

---

#### Original answer

Static members/methods don't work with inheritence (that's true to OO in general and not specific to typescript) because (as @JBNizet commented) all static properties belong to the class itself and not to the instances.

As written in [Wikipedia article](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Method_(computer_programming)#/Static_methods):

> A static method can be invoked even if no instances of the class exist
>   yet. Static methods are called "static" because they are resolved at
>   compile time based on the class they are called on and not dynamically
>   as in the case with instance methods, which are resolved
>   polymorphically based on the runtime type of the object. Therefore,
>   static methods cannot be overridden

Also check this thread: [Why aren't static methods considered good OO practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4002201/why-arent-static-methods-considered-good-oo-practice)

As for what you want to accomplish, you won't be able to get compilation errors for not implementing the static method when extending the class, but you can get runtime errors:

```
class A {
    static fn() {
        throw new Error("not implemented!");
    }
}

class B extends A {
    static fn() {
        console.log("B.fn");
    }
}

class C extends A { }

B.fn(); // ok
C.fn(); // error: not implemented!
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20static%20fn()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20throw%20new%20Error(%22not%20implemented!%22)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20B%20extends%20A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20static%20fn()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(%22B.fn%22)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20C%20extends%20A%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0AB.fn()%3B%20%2F%2F%20ok%0D%0AC.fn()%3B%20%2F%2F%20error%3A%20not%20implemented!))

Comment: Your answer is informative, but remember that I am not trying to do inheritance here (that is why I use _implements_ rather than _extends_. Also, TypeScript is just trying to provide some type-checking and intellisense for JavaScript, JavaScript does not really have class-based inheritance. Therefore, what I am trying to do does not really have to map to the underlying JS; I just want a way to express that a set of classes must all have certain features. There is no real underlying reason why TypeScript cannot provide this check.

Comment: @prmph Well, it'll have to map to the underlying JS, since it's always just JS. Just because there's no reason TS *couldn't* do this doesn't mean it *should*, since it would break its object model (similar to many other object models).

Comment: Check my revised answer

Comment: @Dave: A lot of the type information is discarded by TypeScript when it emits JS; the type info is there mostly for static analysis of the code, not for runtime code generation.

Comment: @Nizan Tomer: Your code works, amazing! I'm curious as to why exactly it works, though. I would have assumed the _CoreInterface()_ function in Test did not have to be static to satisfy the _ConfigConstructor_ interface, but it does. How does that work?

Comment: Also, @Nizan Tomer, you could omit naming the class assigned to the Text constant and the code would still be valid, i.e., const Test: ConfigConstructor = class implements Config { ...

Comment: Yeah, you can omit the 2nd `Test` and it works just the same, I prefer it with it but that's a personal taste. As for why `Test.CoreInterface` needs to be static: because `ConfigConstructor` defines the static parts (or the class part) while the actual class defines (and implements) the instance part. It's the same with `Array` and `ArrayConstructor`, and `Promise` and `PromiseConstructor` (etc..)

Comment: @prmph Yes, I know; that's what I mean by "it's always just JS".

Comment: Is there a way to have ConfigConstructor accept a type parameter? I tried `interface ConfigConstructor<T implements Config>` and `new (): T`, but when passing `Test` it refers to the value being defined, rather than the class. If there's a way to do this, TypeScript would know that `new Test()` is a `Test`, not just a `Config`.

Comment: @JohnLeuenhagen without diving too much into it, I'd say that one solution is to create an interface for `Test` and then do `const Test: ConfigConstructor<Test> ...`.

Comment: Thanks, but what if you need to apply the decorator to the class?

Answer (score 1):

I have been struggling with this dilema aswell, and came up with a solution that combines these concepts:

1. Singleton pattern
2. Abstract function
3. Static function
4. Generic types

End goal was to force all Derivative classes to implement a single function which are being used by a static function to store an static object which are being served statically.

I don't know if this is a hack, but it works.

```
export type StaticThis<T> = { new (): T, product: Product };

export default abstract class SingletonProduct {

  static product: Product;
  
  // Derivative classes must implement this function
  abstract createProduct(context: Context): Product;

  // This function ensures singleton behavior and ensures only one instance of the product
  static getProduct<T extends SingletonProduct>(this: StaticThis<T>, context: 
  Context): Product {
    if (!this.product) {
        this.product = (new this()).createProduct(context)
    }
    return this.product
  }
}
```

Derived class:

```
export default class DerivedProductClass extends SingletonProduct {

  createProduct(context: Context): Product {
    return new Product(...)
  }

}
```

Usage:

```
DerivedProductClass.getProduct(ctx)
```