# Enforce Definition of Static Member in Implementation of Abstract Class in Typescript

Tags: typescript, class, abstract-class

I am working on a WebSocket message system, and need some way to identify the type of a message when it is received. I have an abstract `Message` class, and then have a class for each type of message, which all extend `Message`. I have declared `public static readonly classId` as a member of `Message`, and then set this value for each extension of `Message`. I would like TypeScript to give an error if you try to extend `Message` but don't define `classId`. How could this be done?

Comment: There is currently [no support](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14600) for `abstract static` properties in TypeScript.

Comment: This thread may be of use: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43723313/typescript-abstract-class-static-method-not-enforced

Comment: You have to make classId not static so it can be abstract protected so derived classes are forced to have it as a field

Answer (score 0):

You can not force abstraction down the chain with static methods. Just use `public readonly abstract` if possible:

```
abstract class Message {
   public readonly abstract classId: string;
}

interface IMessageParams {
  classId: string;
}

class MessageTypeA extends Message {
  constructor(public readonly classId = "MessageTypeA") {
    super();
  }
}

const msgA1 = new MessageTypeA();

// leaves software for exachage
const json = JSON.stringify(msgA1);

// comes back to software domain
const messageParams: IMessageParams = JSON.parse(json);

// get back your message type A:
const msgA2  = new MessageTypeA(messageParams.classId);

alert(msgA2 instanceof MessageTypeA); //true
```

Comment: I want each Type of Message to have a unique `classId`. e.g. `MessageTypeA.classId` should be able to be accessed, and should be the same for all instances of `MessageTypeA`.

Comment: I could answer better if you explain how / why you need this id, as if there is 1 to 1 relationship between class type and its id, often you can just use the class for representing the type. either using a mapping or by instanceOf MessageTypeA etc.

Comment: Unfortunately, this information is lost when using `JSON.stringify`. I need this id for adding back the prototype information after using `JSON.parse`

Comment: Not sure how you stringufy but it should never remove public fields. they will convert to and from json just fine. how do you do it?

Comment: `instanceof` does not work after using `JSON.stringify`, as the prototype is not stored in JSON. That's the issue

Comment: JSON is an exchange format not part of the language. All information to do with types, classes, etc. are lost once you serialise your data to be sent out. You need to use the JSON again to recreate instances through the constructor once they are back in your software domain.

Comment: JSON is always type string. That's all it is.

Comment: I am aware of this, which is why I am adding in classId so that I know which prototype to reapply once I parse the serialized data.