# TypeScript abstract static property

Tags: typescript

I am trying to play with CustomElements in JavaScript without a framework, for educational purposes. I am trying to write a base class for my CustomElements, for loading a template and setting up a ShadowDOM. Since the template for a CustomElement depends on the actual implementation, I found myself wanting "abstract static properties".

```
abstract class CustomElement extends HTMLElement {
    abstract static template: HTMLTemplateElement;

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.shadow_root = this.attachShadow({ "mode": "open" });
        this.shadow_root.appendChild(this.constructor.template.content.cloneNode(true)); // How can can I tell typescript, that the constructor does in fact have a template property?
    }    
}

class CustomCircle extends CustomElement {
    static override template = loadTemplate(`CircleTemplate`); // I want this to be static (only do the loading work once, and enforce that everyone implementing "CustomElement" has it

    constructor() {
        super();
        ...
    }
}



class CustomRectangle extends CustomElement {
    static override template = loadTemplate(`RectangleTemplate`);

    constructor() {
        super();
        ...
    }
}
```

Now `abstract static` is not supported in TypeScript, what is my best shot at expressing every class extending `CustomElement` must have a (static) template property?
(Extra: how do I tell TypeScript that `this.constructor` is guaranteed to have the `template` property?)

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have `abstract` at all. Maybe you should replace "JavaScript" with "TypeScript" here since that's the context in which `abstract` makes sense?

Comment: @jcalz: good point, I switched the question to typescript. In honesty I am mildly confused by the language versions (mostly javascript/ecmascript-X), and only found abstract via googling on some third party documentation site and was surprised that I could not find it on mdn.

Comment: some friendly soul added a link to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43723730/258418), unfortunately they removed their comment. While that would be a start, ideally I would not want my user to know about additional interfaces when extending. (After all the idea is to prevent implementation errors which happen due to lack of knowledge/oversight. If the errorchecker needs me to add extra typing (i.e. interfaces) when I use the class, then it seems like a diminished gain)

Answer (score 1):

Based on an answer in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43723730/5053002) it seems the following should do as you require

```
interface CustomConstructor {
    new(): CustomElement;
    template: HTMLElement;
}
abstract class CustomElement extends HTMLElement {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.shadow_root = this.attachShadow({ "mode": "open" });
        this.shadow_root.appendChild(this.constructor.template.content.cloneNode(true));
    }    
}

const CustomCircle: CustomConstructor = class CustomCircle extends CustomElement {
    static template = loadTemplate(`CircleTemplate`);

    constructor() {
        super();
    }
}



const CustomRectangle: CustomConstructor = class CustomRectangle extends CustomElement {
    static template = loadTemplate(`RectangleTemplate`);

    constructor() {
        super();
    }
}
```

If you play around in the code in [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIFcDOYD2BbVHEbKdBXKZAbwChl7kQIB3ACgEoAuNLXPAUQA2EPBHABuOg0h4ADoLiRuACQAqAWQAyQkWLCSAvjRox0IcsCLJBOOABNVI+YoisQcUdxKgA5u2pS9FAQYOhQIIwsyGpajnIKkDqi4BziyAD06ch26Hh4AJ7IMs6Q1rZ20DRGNHAARiSIYMgICpiYPNj4SXrIEAAekCB27THawslNtIHNRCRkFBwBDMvImOiy0KnTy2AAFsCYAHSKYIi7AMq79jhsVMgARHg4Fffc9zgbIPfIBuySK9J9kdMFc7DcAEo4HBgACEx1knzsqH2gjsrD2B0OCFmYFI5BwUEOxQSECxREGYCxNiYADlnq5cegIOw-tMDMsqsZscQmhhOgRgFAWhBuHy+IQeXiKMgALzNVrtMX4VCC4W9AZiYYdPjdcBLBjYRTABBFJwk2VlexxEquAAGKqFwmtJNtrOm3Lm+Kgi1oAPoaw23tZyyM1S5OO1+HBEHIcBAPmEot4ypxUoJFpacDakbw0dj8eE6sGWqVAnGPV9BtOYGNpviLgtNitZpcrFtedOBYgzpcrsk7tT8wJPu2BvWm2DDFDQA) you'll see that TS will complain if a class does not have a `static template`

> Please note: I am NOT a typescript coder, I dabble, but by no means am I at all proficient - I just saw that other answer and guessed what to do :p

Comment: I edited your answer to reduce the number of typescript warnings (induced by my lacking MWE code), since the link is a bit long I took the liberty to edit the answer, hope that is alright with you.

Comment: @ted - all good, the TS Playground stuff was never meant to run :p

Comment: I see how this partly solves my question, do you have any idea how to get rid of the remaining error (that `this.constructor` dos not have a `template` property?). Also forgive me for not accepting the answer yet, while this is the only solution I have seen so far, it requires that a user remembers to use the magic syntax `const CustomRectangle: CustomConstructor = class CustomRectangle`, if a User simply extends the base he will not get warnings. This might be the best we can get, but I was hoping for more :)

Comment: @ted as I said, I'm no typescript coder :p