# Static class that generates instance of itself

Tags: java

What's the downside of instantiating an instance of itself in a static method and then working with this object instead of doing everything statically?

Say I have a class like this:

```
public class MyClass {
    private String foo;
    private String bar;

    private MyClass(String foo, String bar) {
        this.foo = foo;
        this.bar = bar;
    }

    public static String concat(String foo, String bar) {
        MyClass myClass = new MyClass(foo, bar);
        return myClass.concatStrings();
    }

    private String concatStrings() {
        return foo + bar;
    }
}
```

The benefit of this pattern is that I don't have to pass around the input parameters to various private methods. The only bad thing I can think of, is that it might be a performance issue to create an object that I don't really need. But with this very simple example I only notice a real difference (in a quick junit test) with a LOT of iterations (i.e. >=10^8) compared to a simple static class like this:

```
public class MyStaticClass {
    public static String concat(String foo, String bar) {
        return foo + bar;
    }
}
```

Are there any other arguments for or against this pattern?

Comment: If your static utility method needs to be refactored into a class then do it, no downsides. Depending on context it might make more sense to do it in a separate class or in the same class.

Comment: @Oleg say this is a brand new utility class, not some refactoring. The benefit is, I don't have to pass around the arguments internally.

Comment: You should not use the singelton pattern in the first place: http://blog.code-cop.org/2012/01/why-singletons-are-evil.html , And No, there is no rule that "service methods" must (nor should) be `static`...

Comment: @TimothyTruckle It's not a singleton. Every call to concat() instantiates a new instance of the class.

Comment: from the callers side it does not matter. Avoid `static` access unless you have a really good reason...

Comment: You're passing the arguments into the constructor instead of directly into the private method so I'm not really sure where you are seeing the advantage.

Comment: Try adding more methods that require extra or unrelated parameters. Would you like to pass them all at once in constructor every time in every static method ? It soon becomes a mess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem here is the use of static by itself (is [procedural](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4002376/2387977), have some [disavantages](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/98093/172464) and it's [harder to test](https://testing.googleblog.com/2008/08/by-miko-hevery-so-you-decided-to.html)). Most of the times this utility with static methods could be replaced by something else [using OOP](http://www.yegor256.com/2014/05/05/oop-alternative-to-utility-classes.html). So, my suggestion:

```
public class MyClass {
    private String foo;
    private String bar;

    MyClass(String foo, String bar) {
        this.foo = foo;
        this.bar = bar;
    }

    public String concatFooBar() {
        return new Concat(foo, bar).getResult();
    }

}
```

And the utility class:

```
public final class Concat {
    private String foo;
    private String bar;

    Concat(String foo, String bar) {
        this.foo = foo;
        this.bar = bar;
    }

    String getResult() {
        return foo + bar;
    }

}
```